# Customer NPS surveys

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to setup an NPS survey for customers within Marketing cloud. At a high level, below is how i am thinking I would set up.

1. Build email in Marketing cloud with NPS rating --> values submitted get passed to **Responses_DE** in Marketing Cloud using AMPscript
2. If rating is between 0 to 6 --> redirect customers to a cloud page where they submit more information --> those values get passed to the same DE using AMPscript and/or Smart Capture.
3. Create an Automation where the values from **Responses_DE** are passed to Sales Cloud CRM & updates the Survey__c object.

Is it normal to set up NPS surveys in this way or is there an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In email, use `%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesUrl([CloudPageID],'NPS',[1-6]))=%%` on each "star"
Once arriving on Cloud Page, you can fetch the value using `SET @NPS = RequestParameter('NPS')`

Based on this, you can display conditional content:

```
IF @NPS == '1' 
THEN
/* Do something */
ELSEIF  @NPS == '2'
/* Do something else */
...
ENDIF
```

And finally, you can create the record in Sales Cloud using [CreateSalesforceObject function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm):

```
set @SurveyUpdate = 
CreateSalesforceObject('Survey__c', 2, 'ContactID__c', @ContactID, 'NPS', @NPS)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Lukas. Your final step (if i understand correctly) eliminates the need for a journey to update the sales cloud. Also, am assuming this sits in the cloud page.

Comment: Yes, that’s correct @Rahul